# How FireFox sets Origin Request Header?

Tags: jquery, firefox, http-headers, http-post

Can you explain how FireFox sets the Origin header when a CORS HTTP Post is done?
(The reason of this question is to understand why FireFox sets Origin header to NULL in my HTTP Post requests while IE is able to set at least the Referer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Origin header is set the way the spec requires it to be: you take the origin of the page and serialize it.

Note that if your page is at a `file://` URI it will serialize to a null origin.  So depending on how you're testing you may be running into that.

Comment: So how can I make a test from a file that sits on my local machine as an HTML file? No way?

Comment: Run a local web server on localhost.